# Getting access to a multiple layered non-public value

Tags: vb.net, private-members

I'm trying to get access to a property which is under multiple layers of non-public objects

if I copy the path I get:

```
DirectCast((New System.Collections.Hashtable.HashtableDebugView(DirectCast(DirectCast(tool, ESPRIT.KBMDAL.Collections.CuttingTools.CuttingTool).m_Technology, System.__ComObject).m_ObjectToDataMap).Items(0)).Value, System.Dynamic.IDispatchComObject).ComTypeDesc.TypeName
```

if I follow the path using the mouse it would be:

toollist is an arraylist

for each tool in toollist

```
tool -> non-public members -> m_Technology -> non-public members -> m_ObjectToDataMap -> object -> value -> ComTypeDes -> non-public members -> TypeName
```

I've also tried to get to the value step by step with reflection but with that it gets already Nothing for m_Technology.
The DirectCast says, that HashtableDebugView is Public and not accessible. Sadly nothing of that is from me I just try to get read access on this part.

Comment: Show the reflection attempt and we can critique / fix it, that is how you must do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.